In Eclipse, is there a way to configure projects with errors to have a red background instead of just the small red cross icon overlay?
I find the small red cross easy to miss in our huge project lists.
I'm looking for something like the team settings that allow me to mark changed files with a custom background.

Look at the Problems view which shows you all errors clearly.

My problems view is configured to only show problems of the currently selected project. I'm looking for a way to more strongly mark problematic projects in the project explorer. We have team-members who keep committing errors because they miss the small red icon, maybe because they can't see it.

The Problem view's local menu (the vertical dots) lets you quickly switch between the defined filter Configurations. The Git/Committing preference page also has options to warn on--or outright block--committing when Problems exist, at least if they also commit from within Eclipse's UI.
